# SQL LIKE in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, t-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

Before adding this question, I did search on stackoverflow for similar ones but I couldnt find. Most of the questions over internet were using LIKE with a string (for eg LIKE '%ABC%') but I need to compare with an existing column of a different table.

I need to write a linq query for the select statement as below -

```
 select * 
from [dbo].[BaseClaim]
where WPId like (select WPId from UserProfiles where ID='1459')
```

I came up with below linq query but its not working as expected -

```
     var result = (from claimsRow in context.BaseClaims
                          where (from upRow in context.UserProfiles
                                 where upRow.ID == 1459
                                 select upRow.WPId).Contains(claimsRow.WPId)
                          select claimsRow);
```

and the sql that above linq generates is as follows -

```
   SELECT 
   [Extent1].[WPId] AS [WPId]
   FROM [dbo].[BaseClaim] AS [Extent1]
   WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
             1 AS [C1]
                 FROM (SELECT 
                       [UserProfiles].[ID] AS [ID], 
                       [UserProfiles].[WPId] AS [WPId]      
                       FROM [dbo].[UserProfiles] AS [UserProfiles]) AS [Extent2]
                   WHERE (1459 = [Extent2].[ID]) AND ([Extent2].[WPId] = [Extent1].[WPId]))
```

So its clear that my linq is not working as its comparing the baseclaim.wpID to userprofiles.wpid instead of LIKE.

Comment: Why do you use `like`? Are there any `%` characters in `WPId`?

Comment: @Sai look at my answer below. I hope it hits it.

Comment: @GertArnold yes there is % character in WPId

Comment: OK, so some of the answers below could work for you I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent, but there are some methods work similarly, depending on the pattern.

- `string.Contains("pattern")` is equivalent to `LIKE '%pattern%'`
- `string.StartsWith("pattern")` is equivalent to `LIKE 'pattern%'`
- `string.EndsWith("pattern")` is equivalent to `LIKE '%pattern'`

However, in your SQL query the pattern is dynamic, so I don't think there is a good way to convert it straight to Linq. If you know at design time that the pattern fits one of these cases you can use this:

```
var result =
    from claimsRow in context.BaseClaims
    let wpId = context.UserProfiles.Single(upRow => upRow.ID == 1459).WPId
    where claimsRow.WPId.Contains(wpId) // or StartsWith or EndsWith
    select claimsRow;
```

Or possibly

```
var wpId =
    (from upRow in context.UserProfiles
     where upRow.ID == 1459
     select upRow.WPId)
    .Single();
var result =
    from claimsRow in context.BaseClaims
    where claimsRow.WPId.Contains(wpId) // or StartsWith or EndsWith
    select claimsRow;
```

Comment: Linq to SQL says `Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.Contains method.` :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky So I guess that means you have to query for the pattern first?

Comment: @p.s.w.g, thanks for replying. your query return only one wpid from userprofiles I need to compare against all the wpids.

Comment: @Sai Then I'm afraid I don't understand what your original SQL was intended to do. You have `select WPId from UserProfiles where ID='1459'`, which selects only one record, and that's what I tried to duplicate.

Comment: my apologies, I mistakenly assumed this with another query. However i got exception saying that-The methods 'Single' and 'SingleOrDefault' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead. When I changed it to firstordefault it worked but still no results. I'm looking into the generated sql query to find out why.

Comment: Looking at sql query, it generates charindex for comparison and userProfiles.wpId contains % char so this is causing problem. Any ideas on how to overcome it?

Comment: @Sai Well in principle you could filter out the `%` characters in your query (if you know that it's `"%pattern%"`, then `wpId.Substring(1, wpId.Length - 2)` should do the trick). You could also update the database directly.

Comment: I have used Replace function to remove that char. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You must use contain 
for example

```
 .Where(a => a.Name.Contains("someStrig")
```

Contains generate Like when the parameter is constant

Hope it helps

Comment: The OP does use `Contains`! This doesn't say anything.

Comment: what do you mean ? we can write something like this  var query = (from name in Names where name.ToUpper().Contains(someString) select name);

Comment: I say that the OP uses `.Contains(claimsRow.WPId)`. You didn't nail the error, just gave some general remark.

Comment: @Microtechnie, Thanks for replying. I need to resort to other methods instead of contains.

Answer (score 1):

This query works with Entity Framework

```
from claimsRow in context.BaseClaims
let wpId = context.UserProfiles.Where(upRow => upRow.ID == 1459) 
                               .Select(upRow => upRow.WPId)
                               .FirstOrDefault() 
where wpId.Contains(claimsRow.WPId)
select claimsRow
```

But instead of `LIKE` it generates `CHARINDEX` operation

```
SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[BaseClaims] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent2].[WPId] AS [WPId]
                  FROM [dbo].[UserProfiles] AS [Extent2]
                  WHERE [Extent2].[ID] = 1459 ) AS [Limit1] ON 1 = 1
WHERE (CHARINDEX([Extent1].[WPId], [Limit1].[WPId])) > 0
```

Note: with Linq to SQL it throws NotSupportedException:

> Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for
>   the String.Contains method.

Comment: With linq-to-sql you'd have to use [SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340785.aspx). But this is EF.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

The asker said that he has wild cards (`%`) in his UserProfile.WPId that should work like the wildcards in SQL.

You can use this one:

`BaseClaims.Where(b => UserProfiles.Where(u => u.ID == "1459").Any(u => u.WPId.Contains(b.WPId))).ToList();`

In this example, I'm trying to mimic your entities/tables.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<BaseClaim> BaseClaims = new List<BaseClaim>()
        {
            new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "11123411" }, //match 1
            new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "11123123" }, //match 2
            new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "44423411" }, //match 3
            new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "444AAAA" }, //match 3
            new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "444BBBB" }, //match 3
            new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "444QWQEQW" }, //match 3
            new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "2314" },
            new BaseClaim(){ WPId = "3214" }
        };
        List<UserProfile> UserProfiles = new List<UserProfile>()
        { 
            new UserProfile(){ WPId="%112341%", ID="1459" }, //match 1
            new UserProfile(){ WPId="%123", ID="1459" }, //match 2
            new UserProfile(){ WPId="444%", ID="1459" }, //match 3
            new UserProfile(){ WPId="5555", ID="1459" },
            new UserProfile(){ WPId="2222", ID="1459" },
            new UserProfile(){ WPId="1111", ID="4444" },
        };

        char[] asterisk = { '%' };
        List<BaseClaim> result = BaseClaims.Where(b => UserProfiles.Where(u => u.ID == "1459").Any(u => u.WPId.StartsWith("%") && u.WPId.EndsWith("%") ? b.WPId.Contains(u.WPId.Trim(asterisk)) :
                                                                                                        u.WPId.StartsWith("%") ? b.WPId.EndsWith(u.WPId.Trim(asterisk)) : 
                                                                                                        u.WPId.EndsWith("%") ? b.WPId.StartsWith(u.WPId.Trim(asterisk)) :
                                                                                                         false)).ToList();
        //this will result to getting the first 3 BaseClaims

    }
```

Comment: thanks for replying. My WPID in userProfiles contains value in the format - "%12" so when I try to run your query it returns no values.

Comment: I get an exception now- "The method 'System.String Trim(Char[])' is only supported in LINQ to Entities when there are no trim characters specified as arguments." Other thing which I realised is, I cannot trim wildchar(%) from column, because, sometimes wildchar could be in the middle.

Comment: I ended up using context.Database.SqlQuery for getting my work done. thank you for your time and help.