# Filtering on projected property field in LINQ to entities query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

The following **LINQ to Entities** query, a sub-query is performed and its results projected to `MyViewModel`.

I am looking to obtain all `ProjectedModel` objects with the `myText` string variable in the `Text` property of the `SubModel`.

```
var items = (from t1 in db.MyTable
                select new MyModel
                {
                    Id = t1.MyId,
                    SomeItems = (from s1 in db.MyOtherTable
                        where s1.LinkedId == t1.Id
                        select new SubModel
                        {
                            Id = s1.Id,
                            Text = s1.Text
                        })
                }).ToList();
```

Pseudo code would look like:

```
string myText = "abc";
items = items where SomeItems.Text contains myText
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all of the items where *Any* of the sub items have the given text, then that's easy enough to write:

```
items = items.Where(item => 
    item.SomeItems.Any(subItem => subItem.Text.Contains(myText)));
```

If you want *All* of the items to match, then use `All`.  As it is, your requirements are currently incomplete as they assume there is only one sub-item.  (If you know there will always be exactly one sub-item then don't make `SubItems` a collection, make it a single item, and get the first item in the query.)

Comment: Tests on this resulted in "This method is not supported against a materialized query result."

Comment: Just .ToList()'ed SomeItems. Sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this way

### Updated code

```
item.Where(w => myText.Contains(w.Text));
```

or you can use `.StartsWith()` or `.EndsWith()`

reference : [LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17081230/2445111)

My answer is outdated or it may not help you but some more things which may help you

```
var selectItedm = (from a in item   
                  where SqlMethods.Like(a.Text,"%"+myText+"%")  
                  select new {a.Id,a.Text}).ToList();
```

you can use many more `SqlMethods` just include  `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient;` reference

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have used contains but am looking to use it on the nested object's property.

Comment: I'm not looking to filter on Id, I'm looking to filter on the Text property within the SubModel.